# Use OctreePointCloudCompression with PointXYZRGBNormal

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I would like to compress a cloud with point type `pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal`, and have tried to use the `pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression` class.

`pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>` is not pre-instantiated, so I tried to do so myself:

```
#include <pcl/compression/octree_pointcloud_compression.h>
#include <pcl/io/impl/octree_pointcloud_compression.hpp>
#include <pcl/impl/instantiate.hpp>

PCL_INSTANTIATE(OctreePointCloudCompression, (pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal));

pcl::io::compression_Profiles_e compressionProfile = pcl::io::MED_RES_OFFLINE_COMPRESSION_WITH_COLOR;
auto PointCloudEncoder = pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>(compressionProfile, true);
```

As soon as I add the `octree_pointcloud_compression.hpp` header (with the following instantiation lines being in comment), I get the following error:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned long
>   __cdecl pcl::StaticRangeCoder::encodeCharVectorToStream(class std::vector > const &,class
>   std::basic_ostream > &)"
>   (?encodeCharVectorToStream@StaticRangeCoder@pcl@@QEAAKAEBV?$vector@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@AEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@4@@Z)   Test.Core.Native

*Note*: I'm using precompiled PCL 1.8.1 on windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4).

---

*UPDATE*

I attempted to compile a clean project, based on the [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compression.php) (and reduced to minimum). This had the same outcome as in my project.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(point_cloud_compression)

find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (point_cloud_compression point_cloud_compression.cpp)
target_link_libraries (point_cloud_compression ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

**point_cloud_compression.cpp**

```
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <pcl/compression/octree_pointcloud_compression.h>
#include <pcl/io/impl/octree_pointcloud_compression.hpp>
#include <pcl/impl/instantiate.hpp>

#define PCL_INSTANTIATE_OctreePointCloudCompression(T)                \
  template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<T>;

PCL_INSTANTIATE(OctreePointCloudCompression, (pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal));

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    pcl::io::compression_Profiles_e compressionProfile = pcl::io::MED_RES_ONLINE_COMPRESSION_WITH_COLOR;

    pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>* PointCloudEncoder;
    PointCloudEncoder = new pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>(compressionProfile, true);     

    delete (PointCloudEncoder);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the build configuration that you are using ? It is probably a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: I'm not using CMake. Just VisualStudio/MSBuild. I tried to compile the example in the tutorial (using CMake) and had the same outcome (with a different point type). Will update my question with the details now.